# Hue map of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

**How to find the hue map of an image ?**

Based on literature survey, hue map can be obtained by setting the 'S' plane and 'V' plane of HSV image to 1.The matlab code which I have written for finding huemap is given below.  Kindly give me the suggestion whether this code gives the correct result . And I kindly request you to send the matlab code for finding the huemap if the code given below is wrong.

```
I = imread ('D:\image1.png');

figure, imshow(I);
title ('RGB image1')

rir  = size (I, 1);
cic  = size (I, 2);
imnm = rgb2hsv (I);

figure, imshow (imnm);
title ('HSV image1');

imhm = imnm;
for ih = 1 : rir
  for jh=1 : cic
    imhm (ih, jh, 2) = 1;
    imhm (ih, jh, 3) = 1;
  end
end

figure, imshow (imhm);
title ('Hue map');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for all that if you just want to visualise the hue in the hsv space.

```
I   = imread ('image.png');
HSV = rgb2hsv (I);
imagesc (HSV(:, :, 1));
colormap (hsv);
```

or to actually convert back to RGB:

```
HSV(:,:,2:3) = 1;
RGB = hsv2rgb (HSV);
imagesc (RGB);
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I will use this code to find the hue map of an image.